# How to putting image in the label on PyQt?

Tags: python, image, pyqt5

```
form_class = uic.loadUiType("LottoUI.ui")[0]


class WindowClass(QMainWindow, form_class):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.DrawLotsButton.clicked.connect(self.DL)
        self.qPixmapFile = QPixmap()
        self.qPixmapFile.load("Image/Main_Image.png")
        self.qPixmapFile = self.qPixmapFileVar.scaledToWidth(1280)
        self.qPixmapFile = self.qPixmapFileVar.scaledToHeight(800)
        self.Main_Image.setPixmap(self.qPixmapFile)

    def DL(self):
        awnser = DrawLots.MainLot()
        self.qPixmapFileVar = QPixmap()
        self.qPixmapFileVar.load("Image/Dugudugu.jpeg")
        self.qPixmapFileVar = self.qPixmapFileVar.scaledToWidth(418)
        self.qPixmapFileVar = self.qPixmapFileVar.scaledToHeight(475)
        self.A_Label.setPixmap(self.qPixmapFileVar)
        playsound.playsound("Dugudugu_sound.mp3")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = WindowClass()
    myWindow.show()
    app.exec_()
```

I called in all the modules it needed. But I got this error.

```
QPixmap: Must construct a QGuiApplication before a QPixmap
```

Is the PyQt any other way to display the picture on the label?

Comment: The code above shouldn't cause that warning, so you're probably doing something else, like creating the class from another module. Please provide an *actual* [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work. Make sure to replace x and y with your desired constants:

```
#create a x by y pixel, pixel map from your image (only need to do this once in your program)

pix = QtGui.QPixmap(./images/my_image.png)
self.pixmap = pix.scaled(x, y, QtCore.Qt.AspectRatioMode.KeepAspectRatio,QtCore.Qt.TransformationMode.FastTransformation)
       
#now associate the pixel map to the label when you want the label to be your image.

self.label.resize(50, 50)
self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)
```